# Regularly signed out when using firebase authWithPassword

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, firebase, ionic-framework

I have a phonegap app on iOS using firebase for authentication. Logging in is done like so:

```
  var afterLogin = function(error, authData) {
    if (error) { 
      console.log(error); 
      messenger.error(error.message);
      return;
    }
    $scope.loggedIn = $auth.check();
    $scope.$apply();

    $sync.sync();

    messenger.success('Logged in');
  };

  $scope.doLogin = function() {
    mixpanel.track('login');

    if (!$scope.loginForm.email && !$scope.loginForm.password) {
      messenger.error('Enter email and password then tap login');
      return;
    } else if (!$scope.loginForm.email) {
      messenger.error('Enter your email then tap login');
      return;
    } else if (!$scope.loginForm.password) {
      messenger.error('Enter your password then tap login');
      return;
    }

   ref.authWithPassword({
      email    : $scope.loginForm.email,
      password : $scope.loginForm.password
    }, afterLogin);     
  }
```

I check a user's status like this:

```
check: function() {
  var authData = ref.getAuth();
  if (authData) {
    mixpanel.identify(authData.uid);
    mixpanel.people.set({
      "$email": authData.password.email
    });
  }      
  return !!authData;
}
```

It works fine initially, but users get signed out and have to log in again after 12-24 hours of not using the app. Perhaps when the app is shunted out of memory? Obviously this is pretty frustrating, not sure what's causing this. The session length is set to 24 weeks, still having the problem.

Firebase version: 2.1.2
Angular: 1.3.6

Log of localStorage after authenticating with username and password:
[image]
[image]

Coming back a day later after being logged out:
[image]

Contents of the cookie (same logged in or not, no firebase stuff in there):
[image]

Comment: There's quite a bit more detail you could add here to help us understand and repro the issue. The code above seems unlikely to be an exact repro of the code you're using. You haven't included any version info, which could certainly play into a nuance like this. And you haven't listed any of the troubleshooting steps you took or possible causes you ruled out (e.g. is the token being deleted from local storage? does the token still exist? if so, what is the `expires` value if you [break it down](http://jsfiddle.net/firebase/XDXu5/embedded/result/)?)

Comment: @Kato I've added some more information about the issue

Comment: Hey Tom, thanks for the additional info. That does paint a better picture. It looks to me like phonegap is not saving the cookie/storage info. Possibly because it internally uses `file://` and cookies aren't allowed for this? Could you check localStorage/cookies to see if auth is being stored?

Comment: Just tried this out and couldn't repro. We're able to store these and sessions are being persisted.

Comment: @kato I've added the log of the cookie. Doesn't seem like there's anything to do with firebase in there.

Answer (score 0):

It's a parameter in Firebase.

Go on the Dashboard of the Firebase.
Click on "Login & Auth".

Then in the first paragraph, there is an input and select for the Session Length. You can choose how many hours/weekks, etc you want.